# Feynman Lectures p264: How does $r^2 = \rho^2 + a^2$ imply $\rho\, {\rm d}\rho = r\, {\rm d}r$

Tags: derivatives, calculus

I am reading the Feynman Lectures on Physics tome I.

The chapter is about calculating the gravitational field of large object.

In the picture, the line above represents a plane (viewed from the side), with an object at position P, distance from the plane by a distance $a$. "${\rm d}\rho$" is the width of a ring whose radius is $\rho$. And $r$ is the distance from this ring to the object at P.

[image]

One of the step of the calculation is:

> Since $r^2 = \rho^2 + a^2$ then $\rho\, {\rm d}\rho = r\, {\rm d}r.$

How is the above implication obtained?

Comment: That this equation is in Feynman Lectures doesn't make it a Physics one. It's pure Mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a mathematical technique known as taking the [total differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) of both sides of the previous equation.  On the left-hand side, we have $\mathrm{d}(r^2) = 2 r \, \mathrm{d}r$, and similarly for $\rho^2$ on the right.